# getting rid of kubuntu while keeping ubuntu

Tags: kubuntu

I have Ubuntu 15.04 and and I recently  put Kubuntu 14.04 on my computer alongside Ubuntu and this morning Kubuntu kept freezing at the login page. When I put in my passcode, and still won't work even after rebooting several times. I need to get rid of Kubuntu, but I want to keep ubuntu. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Nate.

Comment: Do you have common /home partiton?

Answer (score 0):

Login to Ubuntu, start gparted and remove partition(s) with Kubuntu.

Then run `sudo update-grub`.

If your grub.cfg was on the removed partition, this can be easily fixed.

https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/167850

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24896/discussion-on-answer-by-pilot6-getting-rid-of-kubuntu-while-keeping-ubuntu).